# Delete all files with file extentions not found in list

Tags: vb.net, listbox, delete-file

I have a list box that reads from a textfile to which the user can add and remove file extension types, this compiling a list of files to be excluded from deletion.

how can I program vb.net to delete all files of a given directory example C:\MYFILES except if found in my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will delete all files in a given directory which extension is not in the exclude-list:

```
Dim exclude = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).Select(Function(i) i.ToString)
Dim delQ = From path In IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\MYFILES")
           Where Not exclude.Contains(IO.Path.GetExtension(path))
           Select New IO.FileInfo(path)
For Each delFile In delQ
    delFile.Delete()
Next
```

<sub>Don't forgot the point in the file-extension(f.e. `.txt`)</sub>

Comment: Its now says end of statement expected this i can not work out?

Comment: What framework version are you using? [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397910.aspx) was introduced in 3.5.

Comment: Nope dont worry my systems been playing up today it works now (for now)